# OpenGL ES not displaying VBO on some Android versions

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So I am currently working on a an Android App that uses a native library with OpenGL ES 2.0 that will run on both Android and iOS. Currently, I have two Android devices I am testing on. I have a Kindle Fire HD 2 running Fire OS 4.5.5.1, which works with my app perfectly fine. The other device is a Nexus 4 running Android 4.4.4, which will run a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` command correctly (tested with different clear colors), but it won't draw the VBOs at all.

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.buildertrend.gantt"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
  <application
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:fullBackupContent="false"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.buildertrend.gantt.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/my_paths" />
      <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern="/notes/" /> <!-- FOR GRANTING URI-BASED PERMISSIONS TO SPECIFIC SUB-BRANCHES OF THE PROVIDER -->

    </provider>
    <activity android:name=".GanttActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

GanttActivity.java exerpt:

```
public final class GanttActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private GestureDetectorCompat detectorCompat;
    private ScaleGestureDetector detectorScale;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        GLSurfaceView mGLView = new GanttGLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        setContentView(mGLView);
        mSurfaceView = mGLView;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

GanttGLSurfaceView.java:

```
final class GanttGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final GanttRenderer mRenderer;

    public GanttGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mRenderer = new GanttRenderer(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
    ...
}
```

GanttRenderer:

```
final class GanttRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private final Context appContext;
    private boolean initialized;
    private String fontPath;

    public GanttRenderer(Context context) {
        appContext = context;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        File f = new File(appContext.getFilesDir(), "Arial.ttf");

        if (!f.exists()) {
            AssetManager assets = appContext.getAssets();

            try {
                copy(assets.open("Arial.ttf"), f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("FileProvider", "Exception copying from assets", e);
            }
        }
        fontPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        nativeResize(w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!initialized) {
            nativeInit(fontPath, appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
                    appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            initialized = true;
        }
        nativeRender();
    }
    ...
}
```

Gantt.cpp Excerpts:

```
void appInit(char* fontPath, GLfloat ppi, GLfloat scale) {
    sWindowPpi = ppi;
    sWindowScale = scale;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    generateProjectionMatrix(sWindowWidth, sWindowHeight);
    engine = Engine();
    shader = Shader();
    viewController = ProjectionController();
    polygonRenderer = PolygonRenderer();
    textRenderer = TextRenderer(std::string(fontPath));
    projectFontLowestBearing = textRenderer.prepareSize(
        static_cast<int>(projectFontSizePoints * sWindowPpi / 72));
    headerFontLowestBearing = textRenderer.prepareSize(
        static_cast<int>(headerFontSizePoints * sWindowPpi / 72));

}

void appRender(int tick, GLfloat width, GLfloat height) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (sWindowRotated) {
        generateProjectionMatrix(sWindowWidth, sWindowHeight);
        glViewport(0, 0, sWindowWidth, sWindowHeight);
        sWindowRotated = 0;
    }
    if (!initialized) {
        shader.initialize();
        polygonRenderer.clearPolygons();
        textRenderer.clearTexts();
        clock_t t9 = clock();
        engine.initialize();
        clock_t t0 = clock();
        timeMetric("Engine finished", t9, t0);
        initialized = true;
    }
    viewController.updateViewMatrix(tick);
    CurrentFrameData frame = viewController.getCurrentFrameData();
    textRenderer.calculateOffsetMatrices(frame);
    polygonRenderer.renderPolygons(frame);
    frame.combinedMatrix[14] += 0.1;
    frame.combinedMatrix[16+14] += 0.1;
    textRenderer.renderTexts(frame);
    frame.combinedMatrix[14] -= 0.1;
    frame.combinedMatrix[16+14] -= 0.1;
}
```

PolygonRenderer.cpp Excerpts:

```
void PolygonRenderer::addPolygon(std::vector<GLfloat> vertices, int viewGroup) {

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat),
        vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    polygons.push_back(PolygonRenderObject{vertexBuffer,
        (long)vertices.size() / 6, viewGroup});
}

void PolygonRenderer::renderPolygons(CurrentFrameData frame) {

    glUseProgram(shader.get(0));

    GLuint projectionLocation =
        glGetUniformLocation(shader.get(0), "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix);
    GLuint viewLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader.get(0), "view");

    glBindAttribLocation(shader.get(0), 0, "vertexPosition");
    glBindAttribLocation(shader.get(0), 1, "color");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    std::vector<PolygonRenderObject>::iterator it;
    for (it = polygons.begin(); it != polygons.end(); it++) {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLocation, 1, GL_FALSE,
            &frame.combinedMatrix[16 * it->ViewGroup]);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, it->Buffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, it->Buffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat),
            (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (int)it->VertexCount);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // Clean up
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Shader source for `shaders.get(0)`:

```
std::string noTextureVertex =
    "attribute vec3 vertexPosition;                                         \n"
    "attribute vec3 color;                                                  \n"
    "varying vec3 fragmentColor;                                            \n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;                                               \n"
    "uniform mat4 view;                                                     \n"
    "void main(){                                                           \n"
    "   gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);          \n"
    "   fragmentColor = color;                                              \n"
    "}";
    std::string noTextureFragment =
    "precision mediump float;                                               \n"
    "varying vec3 fragmentColor;                                            \n"
    "void main(){                                                           \n"
    "    gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0);                           \n"
    "}";
```

Edit: Added `glBindAttribLocation`

Comment: Where's your OpenGL code?

Comment: I can add that in, I just thought that it would be an Android error since the program runs on other devices.

Comment: Though I might not need your code, because it looks like a problem I've experienced before and [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324208/opengl-framebuffer-can-clear-it-but-cant-draw-to-it#8529215) is the solution. Check the order of your `gl*` calls.

Comment: I'm going to finish adding my gl methods, because I don't use FrameBuffers. Also, in that one, it looks like it isn't the generation, but the order of binding that was the issue.

Comment: The generation is probably fine on your side too. It will the binding that causes problems, even if you don't have FBO's.

Comment: Alright, but I don't have textures on a lot of my boxes. The current shader I am showing doesn't use them and isn't showing up either.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy The order of binding the objects does not matter, as long as everything is bound when it needs to be bound. Either that poster encountered a driver bug, or much more likely, there was more to the code change than what is shown in the answer.

Comment: How do you know that the attribute locations are 0 and 1? Do you call `glBindAttribLocation()` before linking the program?

Comment: I have added the `glBindAttribLocation` calls, but they still aren't showing up.